Only able to run 1 test on bruno
I have something odd happening on bruno in which I have no idea how to solve.
I am able to run 1 test successfully and then as soon as I try any other tests I get the error:
Error invoking remote method 'send-http-request': Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44394
I have no idea what could be causing this, the environment is set to my localhost
Looking into this a bit more, the error I get is the same error for if the api is not running, so it's as if it thinks after the 1 successful test, the api is no longer running for some reason
